# VBA getting the value of the cell from which a hyper link was clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to send the user to a certian sheet in the workbook based on the value of the hyperlink they click on. "1.01" Is example text in one of the cells that are hyperlinks. I have the event getting triggered when they click with this code, but every time the `BR` is 0.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim BR As Integer
    BR = ActiveCell.Value
    Select Case BR
    Case Is < 2  'case always gets run because BR is always 0
        Worksheets("Appts").Select
    Case 2 To 3
        Worksheets("Next").Select
    Case 3 To 4
        Worksheets("Calls").Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

I think my problem is where I am getting the `ActiveCell.Value` but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Use the Formula rather than Value, or Value2 rather than value

Comment: Side comment. Dont use `Integer` - `Long` is faster.

Comment: Although in this case Single or Double is needed instead of either Long or Integer.

Comment: Honestly it depends on what is being entered in the cell. If there is a data validation which prevents the user from entering anything other than 1 to 4 then `Integer` would be just fine. Else a small error handling can take care of the rest.

Comment: on a side note: the values wont be editable, and will always be #.## .  Id this makes a difference in choosing a data type.

Comment: When you say #.## do you mean for example `1.56` as well or `1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00`? If it is `1.56` then go in for a Single or Double as @HeadofCatering suggested else Integer would be just fine...

Comment: The example value given in the question is 1.01.

Comment: Ah I missed that. Nice Catch @HeadofCatering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

`Activecell` will always give you the value of the cell that is active. If you want the value of the cell which has the hyperlink then use this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim BR As Integer

    BR = Target.Range.Value

    Select Case BR
        Case Is < 2: Worksheets("Appts").Select
        Case 2 To 3: Worksheets("Next").Select
        Case 3 To 4: Worksheets("Calls").Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Since there is lot of comment around using the correct data type. Here is an added info. From your select case it is evident that you are only concerned with values from 1 to 4. In such a case declaring your variable as Integer is just fine. If you are not sure of the user input then introduce a small error handling because then declaring the variable as Integer or Long or Single wouldn't help. For example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim BR As Integer

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    BR = Target.Range.Value

    Select Case BR
        Case Is < 2: Worksheets("Appts").Select
        Case 2 To 3: Worksheets("Next").Select
        Case 3 To 4: Worksheets("Calls").Select
    End Select

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "The value of the cell which has the hyperlink doesn't fall in the range 1 to 4"
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `Target.Range.Value` returns the cell value.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim BR As Integer
    BR = ActiveCell.Formula
    'or
    BR = ActiveCell.Value2
    Select Case BR
    Case Is < 2  'case always gets run because BR is always 0
        Worksheets("Appts").Select
    Case 2 To 3
        Worksheets("Next").Select
    Case 3 To 4
        Worksheets("Calls").Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to fix.

**1. Get the value from the hyperlink**

In order to get the value from `activecell.value`, your hyperlinks need to be linking to themselves. (Right-click a hyperlink and select `edit hyperlink`, select `Place in This Document`, and type the cell's address in the cell reference.)

A better option is to do what Siddharth suggests.

**2. Make sure you select the sheet you want based on the value of the hyperlink**

You also need to fix your case statement. If BR is an integer, any value between 3 and 3.5 will evaluate to 3 and select the "Next" sheet instead of the "Calls" sheet.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't thinking completely through the case yet because I wasn't getting the value.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad you got your issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The value of your cell is probably stored as text rather than a numeric value. Select the cell, press ctrl+1 then change the type to general, or number. Press OK, then push F2 to change the value in the cell, followed by Enter. The data type is now numeric. Run your code again.

Alternatively, instead of this:

```
BR = ActiveCell.Value
```

Use this:

```
BR = CDbl(ActiveCell.Value)
```